# Which options are ther to set up your 3-Tier system

Tags: c#, vb.net

Which options are there to make your 3-Tier System.

Client / Common / Server

Now we work with the entityframework and agatha. But are there other options to make a good 3-Tier system?

The agatha framework, makes for us the request/response on the common site.
On the server site the response will be filled in.

But are there other framework to do all that work for you? Or should you do it without such framework. And call at the server site stored procedure? Or with LINQ? With the agatha we query the repository's with some LINQ queries.

But i am wonna know if there are other ways to do the communication. Maybe there are other and better ways to do it.

I hope i get some usefull answer. Where i can read some new things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately there is nothing in any of the Frameworks that you could not, at some level, do yourself.  The Frameworks VASTLY simplify your life, however.

For calling the DB, you can use System.Data classes, for calling out to the UI (from middle-tier) you can use BCL classes, etc.

Alternatively, there are, indeed, additional frameworks that do a lot of that for you.  NHibernate (in place of Entity Framework), ASP MVC for end-to-end, etc.  While no two frameworks are exactly the same, most of them (now) have some core functionality that you can always expect.  My recommendation would be to go to Google (or bing, or yahoo, or wherever) and search for things like "Object Relational Mapping" "User Experience" and browse through what you find.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can everything without any framework. 
But not everything is good. Somebody says work with stored procedures. Others say to use repository's en use linq to sql to get the right information.

And offcourse the frameworks help you. But i don't have any experience with other frameworks. So i can't say which framework works good.